# How to remove overlaid background during the "loading initial ramdisk" screen?

Tags: linux, boot, grub, themes, splash

I am on Debian, and have set a custom grub theme, with custom background and stuff.

It works, but when Linux boots, during the "loading initial ramdisk" screen, it overlays the default Debian splash on top of the background.

How do I stop it from happening?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

Setting a theme on grub won't set `GRUB_BACKGROUND`. The `theme.txt` manual mentioning `desktop-image` as the background is not exactly what you would expect.

There is a slight offset, but manually setting in `GRUB_BACKGROUND` in `/etc/default/grub` works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).